# Column of type "timestamp(6) with timezone" and "current time" difference in minutes

Tags: oracle12c

I have Oracle 12c DB table and one of it's column utc_timestamp is of type

`UTC_TIMESTAMP  TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE`

It stores timestamp in UTC while `current_timestamp` and `systimestamp` both gives timestamp in different timezones.

How can I get time difference in `MAX(utc_timestamp)` and `current_timestamp` in minutes ignoring time difference due to different time zones.

For example:

```
select current_timestamp from dual;
Gives=> 23-AUG-17 04.43.16.253931000 PM AMERICA/CHICAGO

select systimestamp from dual;
Gives=> 23-AUG-17 05.43.16.253925000 PM -04:00

select max(UTC_TIMESTAMP) from table_name;
Gives=> 23-AUG-17 09.40.02.000000000 PM +00:00
```

For above condition when I run SQL to check time difference between in `MAX(utc_timestamp)` and `current_timestamp` I should get number 3.

I think I need something like:

```
select (extract(minute from current_timestamp) - extract(minute from max(UTC_TIMESTAMP)) * 1440) AS minutesBetween from table_name;
```

But different timezones are messing it up and I get negative number like -4317. This might be correct as current_timestamp will be higher than max(utc_timestamp) being in CST. So I tried:

```
select (extract(minute from CAST(current_timestamp as TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE)) - extract(minute from max(UTC_TIMESTAMP)) * 1440) AS minutesBetween from table_name;
```

This SQL runs without error but producing a big negative number like -83461. Please help me find what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two problems here.

One is to convert `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to UTC. That is trivial:

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' from dual   [.....]
```

(use the AT TIME ZONE clause https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699)

The other is that the difference between two timestamps is an interval, not a number.

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
       - to_timestamp_tz('24-AUG-17 04.00.00.000 AM UTC', 'dd-MON-yy hh.mi.ss.ff AM TZR')
from dual;
```

produces something like

```
+00 00:02:39.366000
```

which means + (positive difference) 00 days, 00 hours, 02 minutes, 39.366 seconds.

If you just want the minutes (always rounded down), you may wrap this whole expression within `extract( minute from < ...... > )`. Be aware though that the answer will still be 2 (minutes) even if the difference is five hours and two minutes. It is probably best to leave the result in interval data type, unless you are 100% sure (or more) that the result is always less than 1 hour.

Comment: Thank you for your input mathguy. I know the result can go beyond 1 hour. So, this would work for me if I can somehow convert hours in minutes and add to the minute part. The result is used in an alert condition: If the result is more than predefined minutes then alert is triggered. So, I need result as a single number which should be actual difference in two timestamps in minutes.

Comment: @300 - Then **no**, you don't. Instead, compare to an interval, as in `> interval '45' minute` if you want records more than 45 minutes old. That way you don't ever have to worry about numbers, only timestamps and intervals.

Comment: I think I got it following your suggestion and blowing it up to convert hours/days in minutes and adding those to minutes part to finally get the difference in minutes.
`select 
(extract(day from (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - max(UTC_TIMESTAMP))) * 1440)
+ (extract(hour from (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - max(UTC_TIMESTAMP))) * 60)
+ (extract(minute from (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - max(UTC_TIMESTAMP))))
AS minutesBetween from commsdesk.fact_realm_utilization;`

Comment: @300 - way too complicated. What is wrong with leaving the difference between timestamps as an INTERVAL data type, and comparing to an INTERVAL constant as I suggested?

Comment: I agree it's quite verbose and complicated. I didn't quite understand your second suggestion to compare with interval. Also, the result (difference in two timestamps) can be anything from 1 minute to few thousand minutes. As this SQL will be used in a trigger condition in a different application which can check only for single number in minutes. So I came up with the ugly version of the SQL. I would be happy to use another better/cleaner SQL if possible.

Comment: @300 - It is not true that a trigger "can check only for single number in minutes." Edit the trigger: where the comparison is, for example,  ` ... > 45` - meaning you compute a long and ugly formula to convert everything into minutes - you can change that (in the trigger) to `... > interval '45' minute`. Now `...` is not the long and ugly formula where you extract days, hours, minutes, ... and do computations; instead, it is just the formula from my Answer, or something similar to it. It is just the difference of two timestamps (with time zone, specifically 'UTC').

Comment: Actually the trigger condition I mentioned about is not in SQL (or any database). It's in a different application altogether. This SQL will be run from that application and returning number will be checked again a set of threshold values. My bad for not stating this clearly.

Comment: @300 OK, now it all makes sense! Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but may still be relevant, so...

I had a similar issue and solved it by simply putting a CAST in front of both dates/timestamps, subtracting them from each other (got diff in days) and multiplying with number of minutes per day like this:

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR(
(CAST (systimestamp at time zone 'utc' AS DATE) - CAST (systimestamp at time zone 'utc'-1 AS DATE)) * 24 * 60) DURATION
FROM dual;
```

Last timestamp (show with the minus one) would be from the database table.